# flutter gridview lagging UI

Tags: caching, loading

i am getting list of a data from API. and the length of list is 18 now after every 8 iam showing ad. now on every end of scroll I again call API and add more 18 length of data in same list in staggered gridview. as scroll come to an end I call API and add more 18 length list of data to staggered gridview. Now problem is that Ui performance is too bad.

i am expecting that UI didnt update recent updated data, after adding new data in the list in gridview